# Competition with computers

Tags: vb.net

I want to avoid running Button1.PerformClick () once score is up.

I tried exit sub, but it was useless.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private a, b As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim randomNum1 As Integer
        Randomize()
        randomNum1 = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
        Dim randomNum2 As Integer
        Randomize()
        randomNum2 = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
        a = randomNum1
        b = randomNum2
        TextBox1.Text = a
        TextBox2.Text = b
        If a = b Then
            Delay(2)
            Button3.PerformClick()
        Else
            Delay(2)
            Button1.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If a = b Then
            MsgBox("score")
            TextBox3.Text = +1
            Else
            MsgBox("Retry")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If a = b Then
            MsgBox("computer score")
            TextBox4.Text = +1
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox1.Text = 10 Then
            Form2.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

button3 is automatically clicked even though button2 is clicked.

Comment: You might want to look at how to create your own method and call these instead of the button click.

Comment: I don't really understand your code. What is putting the score up ? Maybe the Button1_Click Sub could be a separated Sub and you just put a boolean like `Dim isScoreUp as Boolean = False`and when the scoreis up the boolean go true. Then on Button1.Click you just check the value of the boolean

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking with this code is very confused. First you must turn on Option Strict (see my comment) This will help you to know when you are comparing strings to numbers which can have unexpected results. Text properties are Strings and may not be successfully compared to numbers.

Second, use descriptive names for your controls. It will help clear your thinking

Since you are working in vb.net use the Random class available in .net. Declare as a 
Form level variable. Then you can simply use the .Next method.

I am not sure why you would want Button1.Click not to run but there is a .Enabled property that you can set to False.

If you have code that you want to call from more than one Event Procedure, write your own Sub or Function and call that from the Event procedure.

```
Private Rand As New Random
Private a, b As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'The text boxes 3 and 4 need a text value that will convert to a valid Integer
    TextBox1.Text = "0" 'Computer's Number
    TextBox2.Text = "0" 'Players's Number
    TextBox3.Text = "0" 'Computer's Score
    TextBox4.Text = "0" 'Player's Score
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a = Rand.Next
    b = Rand.Next
    TextBox1.Text = a.ToString 'Display Computer's number
    TextBox2.Text = b.ToString 'Display 
    If a = b Then
        MessageBox.Show("It's a tie, try again")
    ElseIf a > b Then
        MessageBox.Show("Computer Wins")
        TextBox3.Text = (CInt(TextBox3.Text) + 1).ToString
    ElseIf a < b Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Win")
        TextBox4.Text = (CInt(TextBox4.Text) + 1).ToString
    End If
    If CInt(TextBox3.Text) = 10 Then 'When the computers score = 10
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```